# MySQL for Vistual Studio failed installation

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2017

I couldn't find anything on google about this or it's just i don't know what the exact word to type on google

[image]

Could someone please help me .
Thank you

Comment: Ow wow . Thank you . I'll try that

Comment: In which sense is this question related to MySQL Workbench? Please take care to pick the proper tags to the right people help you and avoid unnecessary work for those not interested in your question! I removed the references to MySQL Workbench.

Comment: It has been solved sir . By downgrading 2017 to 2015. Thank you and sorry for the unnecessary tag